# Can't connect to some (not all) repository servers

Tags: apt, repository

I have some head crunch issues with updating my Ubuntu 12.04 server system.
When I issue the following command (as root):

```
apt-get update
```

...nothing happens and after a while apt-get gives up with loads of errors like:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to nl.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
```

Below a copy of the stdout. Please note that I didn't wait for the command to finish and aborted it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to save some time

```
root@webserver:/var/log/apt# apt-get update
0% [Connecting to nl.archive.ubuntu.com (213.136.29.218)]^C
```

This is how my sources.list looks like:

```
root@webserver:/var/log/apt# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted 
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted 
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted 
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted 
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

My `/etc/apt.apt.conf` is empty and no proxy is in use

```
root@webserver:/var/log/apt# cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
root@webserver:/var/log/apt# echo $http_proxy

root@web-octoplus01:/var/log/apt# echo $HTTP_PROXY

root@web-octoplus01:/var/log/apt#
```

Using the [US mirrors](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com) gives the same result. Special with the US mirrors is that every third try it suddenly works!
(Only the 91.189.91.14 address works, the rest results in the same errors)

```
root@web-octoplus01:/var/log/apt# host us.archive.ubuntu.com
us.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.14
us.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.15
us.archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.13
us.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::15
us.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::13
us.archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::14
```

Can it be that my server is on some inconsistent black-list at Ubuntu?
What do I not see?

Comment: have you tried to use another server as source for your updates?

Answer (score 3):

Since the IPv4 version works, you can change the priority of the type of connection to the destination node from IPv6 to IPv4 in the /etc/gai.conf file (which controls the destination address selection).

uncomment the following in the document:

precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100

As stated in the file, this way sites that prefer IPv4 connection can be connected with IPv4 instead of IPv6.